Writing a recursion progam in armV7 to solve a power function
Can anyone help me understand what i am doing wrong in this program.  I am trying to learn how to write recursion functions in arm but am struggling with the concept.  The function is supposed to solve the power of a number.
_start:
    mov r0, #2 @x value
    mov r1, #10 @y value 
    bl pow
    
stop:
    b stop
    
/*
    int pow(int x, int y) {
        if (y == 0)
            return 1;
        else
            return x * pow(x, y – 1);
    }
------------------
contents        address
- Y             fp - 12
- X             fp - 8
-Old Fp         fp - 4
-LR             fp + 4
*/

pow:
    push {fp, lr}
    add fp, sp, #4
    sub sp, sp, #8
    str r0, [fp, #-4]
    str r1, [fp, #-8]
    
@body
    ldr r1, [fp, #-8]
    ldr r2, [fp, #-4]
    cmp r1, #0
    beq base_case
    sub r1, r1, #1
    bl pow
    str r0, [fp, #-12]
    ldr r0, [fp, #-12]
    bl pow
    ldr r2, [fp, #-4]
    mul r0, r0, r2
    b done
    
base_case:
    mov r0, #1

done:
    add sp, sp, #4
    pop {lr, fp}
    bx lr

Ive tried a few different iterations of this program and cant seem to get it correct.
